# Output List Duplicating Values

Tags: python, list, recursion

My function same_num takes values that are common to both sorted lists and appends them onto 'result'. It's using recursion and two offsets, pos1 and pos2 that are always initially set to 0, to compare values in the list. When running the function, it works fine the first time, however if I run the function a second time, the original result is appended with the answer I got from running it initially. Where am I going wrong?

```
result=[]

def same_num(list1,list2,pos1,pos2):
    list1=sorted(list1)
    list2=sorted(list2)

    if pos1==len(list1) or pos2==len(list2):
        return result
    if list1[pos1]==list2[pos2]:
        result.append(list1[pos1])
        return same_num(list1,list2,pos1+1,pos2+1)    
    if list1[pos1]>list2[pos2]:
        return same_num(list1,list2,pos1,pos2+1)
    if list1[pos1]<list2[pos2]:
        return same_num(list1,list2,pos1+1,pos2)
```

For example:

```
same_num([3,1,2,4],[3,1,2,4,5,6],0,0)=>[1,2,3,4]
```

Rerunning the previous example in the shell produces:

```
same_num([3,1,2,4],[3,1,2,4,5,6],0,0)=>[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

when it should still produce:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: are you resetting result to an empty list each time you run the function?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `result` is a global variable. [Globals are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad)! You are adding stuff to `result` (`result.append(...)`) but never clearing it out after the first invocation of the `same_num` function.

(Although I can see why you are taking this approach, because conceptually it is often easier to approach recursive functions using global variables.)

If you make `result` a parameter of the `same_num` function that can be passed to recursive invocations of the same function... this issue is fixed.

```
def same_num(list1,list2,pos1,pos2,init_result=None):
    # IMPORTANT: see remark below on why init_result=[]
    # would not do what you expect
    result = init_result if init_result is not None else []

    list1=sorted(list1)
    list2=sorted(list2)

    if pos1==len(list1) or pos2==len(list2):
        return result
    if list1[pos1]==list2[pos2]:
        result.append(list1[pos1])
        return same_num(list1,list2,pos1+1,pos2+1,result)    
    if list1[pos1]>list2[pos2]:
        return same_num(list1,list2,pos1,pos2+1,result)
    if list1[pos1]<list2[pos2]:
        return same_num(list1,list2,pos1+1,pos2,result)

# multiple invocations will return the same (expected) result
print( same_num([3,1,2,4],[3,1,2,4,5,6],0,0) )
print( same_num([3,1,2,4],[3,1,2,4,5,6],0,0) )
```

By the way, see ["Common Python Gotchas: Mutable default arguments"](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) for why I used `init_result=None` as the default, rather than `init_result=[]`.

Comment: I had tried making 'result' a local variable, but any time I would run the function it would output an empty list.

Comment: Why is `None` better than `[]`? The link states `None` is usually a good choice but offers no explanation as to why.

Comment: @mista619, certainly. If `result` is a local variable, then it will not be saved across recursive invocations. This is why I added it as an additional (optional) parameter to the function, for recursive invocation. Compare this to a standard [recursive implementation of QuickSort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Algorithm).

Comment: @dmlittle, `None` is a better choice because it is not mutable, unlike `[]` which is. With a mutable default argument, it is easy to write a function which inadvertently modifies the object referred to by its default argument for future invocations; because an immutable object can't be modified, this problem won't occur.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the help as well as providing the additional links for clarification.

Comment: Sure! Lastly, I'd mention that although this is a useful exercise for learning algorithms, Python's built-in [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) does everything you want here in one fell swoop. Try this: `print( {3,1,2,4} & {3,1,2,4,5,6} )` => `set([1, 2, 3, 4])`

Answer (score 0):

> When running the function, it works fine the first time, however if I
>   run the function a second time, the original result is appended with
>   the answer I got from running it initially.

That is the exact issue. You are not emptying the previous `result` before you call it again. `result` still contains the values from the first time you ran the function.

For example, try running it like this instead:

```
output = same_num([3,1,2,4],[3,1,2,4,5,6],0,0)
print output
result = []
output = same_num([3,1,2,4],[3,1,2,4,5,6],0,0)
print output
```

Both outputs will be `[1,2,3,4]`